# Find duplicate entries in a file for each day

Tags: c#

I want to write a c# code that reads my file which is in the below given format and prints all the duplicate entries for each date along with the number of occurrence.

Example.txt :

```
March 03 2014 abcd March 03 2014 def March 03 2014 abcd March 04 2014 xyz March 04 2014 xyz
```

Output :

```
March 03 2014 abcd 2
March 04 2014 xyz 2
```

Can someone help me with this?

I was thinking about using dictionary where the event would be my key and for each duplicate event, I would increment the value. But I am not sure how to group the result for each day.

Comment: Show what you have tried, what you have so far.

Comment: Wow, thats your file?  That looks kind of hard to split apart the dates from the text.  I assume your text has spaces, too.  Is that your real data?

Comment: Note for your use, you probably don't need a Dictionary more like you need a HashSet.

Comment: Are you really set on using a plain file instead of storing the data in a database?

Comment: @Vasil I'm guessing this is a HW assignment... hence not even a standard delimiter

Comment: I have to use a file. It would have been much easier if it was database.

Comment: @user3380892 Does your file read line by line?  Or is it all one line?

Comment: This is my actual data, except I have replace my event with "abc","xyz". This is not a homework assignment. Although that did made me smile. If only I could go back to school.

Comment: If you don't even have line breaks, then this is going to be really tough... what kind of sick person made a file in this format?!

Comment: @EvanL I am not sure if his data is split by `\r\n`.  I don't know if your editing of his question is accurate.

Comment: Re-edited to fit the spec.

Comment: @EvanL You make a good point though; I think the OP should actually manually reformat the data putting in newlines where necessary.  I think this is the recommended course of action.  Then, the rest is easy.

Comment: @user1477388 Yep `ReadLine()` into a `List<string>` or something is probably the easiest way here.

Comment: @user1477388 If you can figure where to put the newlines, then you don't need to put them into the file.

Comment: the "events" (abcd, ...), can contain spaces?

Comment: So have a line break for every new date?

Comment: FelipeP - no spaces in events

Comment: in March 3 2014 there is an event "def" and another named "abcd", the output has to show only one of them?

Comment: FelipeP Only the events that are duplicate. Since "def" occurs only once, we don't have to show that

Comment: done, updated the answer, now you'll have a hard work choosing one :)

Answer (score 3):

It might be good case for LINQ power:

```
var input = "March 03 2014 abcd March 03 2014 def March 03 2014 abcd March 04 2014 xyz March 04 2014 xyz";
var format = "MMMM dd yyyy";

var results = input.Split(' ')
                   .Select((v, i) => new { v, i })
                   .GroupBy(x => x.i / 4, x => x.v, (k, g) => g.ToList())
                   .Select(g => new
                   {
                       Date = DateTime.ParseExact(String.Join(" ", g.Take(3)), format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                       Event = g[3]
                   })
                   .GroupBy(x => x)
                   .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                   .Select(g => new
                   {
                       Item = g.Key,
                       Count = g.Count()
                   });

foreach (var i in results)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", i.Item.Date.ToString(format), i.Item.Event, i.Count.ToString());
```

Prints exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Going by your original description of the problem and sample data, this code will probably work with some tweaks.  You could probably do it using some of the LINQ libraries as well.

```
        List<String> outputStringList = new List<string>();

        IEnumerable<String> stringEnumerable = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"c:\tmp\test.txt");

        System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<String> uniqueHashSet = new System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<String>();

        foreach (String line in stringEnumerable) { uniqueHashSet.Add(line); }

        foreach (String output in uniqueHashSet)
        {
            Int32 count = stringEnumerable.Count(element => element == output);

            if (count > 1) { outputStringList.Add(output + " " + count); }
            //if (count > 1) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(output + " " + count); }
        }
```

I see that you changed the formatting of your data while I was writing up my answer.  Please disregard as this solution will no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I've written this to be simple to read, with comments explaining the process.

If you are also the one writing this file, to separate each "file" with a Record separator, which if you look on the ascii table has a value of 30. If this is not the case, and you HAVE to use the file format given in the OP let me know and I can add a case for that.

```
// Reads in the entire file into one string variable.
string allTheText = File.ReadAllText(string filePath);

// Splits each "file" into a string of its own.
string[] files = allTheText.Split((char)30);

// Do this if you have a newline inbetween each "file" instead of just spaces.
string[] files = File.ReadAllLines(string filePath);

// Make a Dictionary<string, string> to hold all these (you could use DateTime but I opted to not).
Dictionary<string, string> entries = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach(string file in files)
{
    // Now lets get the Date of this "file".
    // We need the index of the 3rd space
    var offset = file.IndexOf(' ');
    offset = file.IndexOf(' ', offset+1);
    offset = file.IndexOf(' ', offset+1);

    // Now split up the string by this offset
    string date = file.Substring(0, offset-1);
    string filecont = file.Substring(offset);

    // Only add if it isn't already in there
    if(!entries.Keys.Contains(date))
        entries.Add(date, filecont);
}

// Print them out
foreach(string key in entries)
{
    Console.WriteLine(key + " " + entries[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your text by using a Regular Expression.

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, Int32>> SearchDuplicates(string file){
    var file = File.ReadLines(file);
    var pattern = new Regex("[A-Za-z]* [0-9]{2} [0-9]{4} [A-Za-z]*");
    var results = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    foreach(var line in file) {
        foreach(Match match in pattern.Matches(line)) {
            if(!results.ContainsKey(match.Value))
                results.Add(match.Value, 0);
            results[match.Value]++;
        }
    }

    return results.Where(v => v.Value > 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using regex

```
string input = "March 03 2014 abcd March 03 2014 def March 03 2014 abcd March 04 2014 xyz March 04 2014 xyz";

List<string> dates = new List<string>();
string[] splitted = input.Split(' ');
for (int i = 0; i < splitted.Length; i = i + 4)
{
    string strDate = splitted[i] + " " + splitted[i + 1] + " " + splitted[i + 2] + " " + splitted[i + 3];

    if (!dates.Contains(strDate))
    {
        dates.Add(strDate);
        if (Regex.Matches(input, strDate).Count > 1)
            Console.WriteLine(strDate + " " + Regex.Matches(input, strDate).Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is very easy to understand. I am going to try this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can tokenize it based on the month delimiter if you want

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    var str = "March 03 2014 abcd March 03 2014 def March 03 2014 abcd March 04 2014 xyz March 04 2014 xyz";

    var rawResults = tokenize (str).GroupBy(i => i);

    foreach (var item in rawResults) {
        Console.WriteLine ("Item {0} happened {1} times", item.Key, item.Count());
    }
}

static List<String> tokenize (string str)
{
    var months = new[]{ "March", "April", "May" }; //etc

    var strTokens = str.Split (new []{ ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var results = new List<string> ();

    var current = "";
    foreach (var token in strTokens) {
        if (months.Contains(token)) {

            if (current != null && current != "") {
                results.Add (current);
            }

            current = token + " ";
        } else {
            current += token + " ";
        }
    }           

    results.Add (current);

    return results;
}
```

Better yet, use a parser combinator to do it